# Error in RSA algorithm output when dealing with large integers

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I wrote code to generate pseudo-random prime numbers, public/private keys, etc. for the sake of implementing RSA encryption (for personal amusement and nothing more). I am able to successfully encode text, generate the public/private key, encrypt, decrypt, and decode when the encoded text is an integer ~10^12 or less. e.g.

```
original message: hello
plaintext equivalent: 448378203247
public key: (540594823829, 65537)
private key: (540594823829, 261111754433)
ciphertext: 63430225682
```

Decrypting the ciphertext successfully returns the original plaintext.

However, when my encoded text is a larger integer, the process fails. e.g.

```
original message: a man a plan a canal panama
plaintext equivalent: 39955594125525792198857762901926727877852838348601974063966023009
public key: (662173326571, 65537)
private key: (662173326571, 29422219265)
ciphertext: 429717871098
```

In this case the ciphertext is much much smaller than the plaintext, which makes one suspect that something in the encryption process went wrong. And sure enough, I decrypt the ciphertext and get 58514793315 (clearly not the original plaintext).

I'm thinking the issue is how Python implements large numbers/calculations with large numbers, and the fact that I'm not aware of how to deal with that. For what it's worth my code to encrypt/decrypt is simply

```
pow(m, e, n) # plaintext, encryption exponent, modulus
pow(c, d, n) # ciphertext, decryption exponent, modulus
```

and the code for encoding text is from
http://gist.github.com/barrysteyn/4184435#file_convert_text_to_decimal.py

How do I ensure that calculations with these large integers are carried out as I wish (and do not result in truncated/incorrect answers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without breaking your messages into blocks, you can only encrypt messages smaller than the modulus with RSA. If you're doing this as a programming exercise, don't try to encrypt anything larger than the modulus. If you're doing this as actual cryptography, **don't**. Get a crypto library. Doing your own crypto is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Could you clarify as to how I could go about breaking the plaintext into blocks (e.g. would it work to simply break it into chunks of 5, encrypt, and then bring the chunks back together)? And yes, this is for a learning exercise/my amusement only.

Comment: If you're doing it for fun, that'd work. You could also express the number in base `N`, where `N` is the modulus, then encrypt the digits separately.